# How do I wrap an ambiguous name? Can you fix my good_value() function?

Tags: javascript

I have this function -

```
function good_value(item) 
{
      if (typeof(item)=="undefined")
           return "";
      return item.toString(); 
}
```

So I might like to write -

```
abc = def + good_value(xyz);
```

As you can guess I'm trying to write a function that 
I can throw around any variable name to get a string 
no matter what the variable is, no matter if it's 
undefined, no matter if it's even undeclared.

But I'm getting an error in the line that calls the 
function; complaining that the argument is undefined.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Well you didn't actually *include* "the line that calls the function".  In any case, the built-in function `String()` does what you want, almost.

Comment: Show us how you call the function + `typeof(item)` must be replaced with `typeof item`

Comment: @Weedoze `typeof (item)` is fine, though  the parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: OP if you call `good_value(someUndefinedVariable)` then the evaluation of the function parameter can cause the error you're getting. There's nothing you can do about that in a function call; you'd have to test the variable explicitly first.

Comment: @Pointy Well ok then, I didn't know. Thanks for that !

Comment: adiga - I'm not in control of whether xyz is declared/defined or not.  That's the whole point.  And the point of functions is that you write the logic once, and can use it again and again wherever an unknown variable arises.  That's why, pointy, I don't want to have to keep writing "if (xyz===undefined)" everywhere there might be an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer.  I just rewrite it as -

```
abc = def + good_value("xyz");
```

and rewrite the good_value function using a *try...finally*
block enclosing an eval(str) function, where str is the source code I need involving xyz.

*(brilliant.. although I say so myself!!)*